How do we know when total variation diminishing (TVD) schemes are appropriate to apply to a given PDE?
I am working on the research of hydrodynamics and see some researchers applying the TVD numerical scheme to flow equations such as shallow water equations or kinematic wave equations. But in their work, they never illustrated that their considered model has the TVD property. Is it obvious? Or there are some works that confirm the TVD property of the mentioned equation.

Theorem 5.2 (Godlewski & Raviart 1991)
Assume that the inital condition $u_0$ of the Cauchy problem for a nonlinear hyperbolic conservation law is $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Then the Cauchy problem has a unique entropy solution $u\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d\times (0,T))$ satisfying $$\|u(\cdot,t)\|_{L^\infty} \leq \|u_0\|_{L^\infty} $$ for almost all $t>0$.
Moreover, if $u$ and $v$ are solutions corresponding to initial conditions $u_0$ and $v_0$, then $$ u_0 \geq v_0~\text{a.e.}\implies u(\cdot,t)\geq v(\cdot,t)~\text{a.e.}$$
Finally, if $u_0\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)\cap \mathrm{BV}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, then $u(\cdot,t)\in \mathrm{BV}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $$ \mathrm{TV}(u(\cdot,t)) \leq \mathrm{TV}(u_0).$$
Godlewski, Edwige; Raviart, Pierre-Arnaud, Hyperbolic systems of conservation laws, Mathématiques & Applications (Paris). 3-4. Paris: Ellipses, 252 p. (1991). ZBL0768.35059.

Oh! It is the valuable answer for me. Thank you very much!
